# why is try except block not working in visual studio code for python 3.7?

Tags: python, error-handling, exception, visual-studio-code

When implementing a try/except block, VS Code does not recognize the specified exception or any exception for that matter. Ex:

```
try:
    x = 1/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("You cannot divide by zero ")
```

throws an exception error and does not print "You cannot divide by zero" when executed through the terminal. VS Code doesn't seem to be recognizing any exceptions. I've tried using the same code in IDLE and Sublime and it prints the correct message. Does anyone have any suggestions for fixing this?

Other information: I'm using the python extension from Microsoft and have no other extensions in VS Code.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you *run* the code, or are you just looking at an IDE warning?

Comment: _this code throws an exception error_ What exception does it throw?

Comment: What do you mean vscode doesn't recognize it? Vscode is a text editor...

Comment: @user2357112 I did 'run' the code. The program halts and the debugger displays the "ZeroDivisionError" instead of handling the exception and printing the message.

Comment: Where does it halt? It sounds like you might have a breakpoint or some sort of "break on exceptions" setting set.

Comment: It sounds like the VS debugger got control before the Python interpreter had a chance to catch the exception. In the debugger, trying entering the command to just continue execution.

Comment: @user2357112 I just tried the program on my Mac and it works fine. So I am only getting the issue on windows. I'll have to look into this more as I code on both OS. I will update if I find a solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @martineau that worked! Thank you!

Comment: Solution can be found here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/6238#issuecomment-503641878. I believe the problem is due to a setting that may have been inadvertently selected. I.e. you may have configured the debugger to `break on all exceptions`

Answer (score 7):

This happens when you tick the `Raised Exceptions` option in `Breakpoints` section of the debug window panel on the left (once in the debug mode). See the screenshot here in the related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/6238).

Untick this option and you will have your expected behavior. The behavior you describe is intended when that option is ticked.