# Visual Studio Code Bugged when running python try and except for ValueError

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, valueerror

If I run this code in vscode the exception gets raised and not handled by Try/Except, But if I run it in python Idle the opposite occurs where Try/Except handles the exception [Screenshot of the code being ran in vscode and the exception being raised when it shouldn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vySaw.png)

As a result of this I feel like vscode is bugged when running this try/except code. Is there any way around this.[Screenshot of code being run in idle and the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXrli.png)

This code is part of a much bigger project however I've isolated it down to this very try and except piece of code. It even happens when I write try: except ValueError in its simplest form: [vscode running try: except ValueError: Simple Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crt82.png)

this is my first post on this platform so I apologize in advance if it's incorrectly formatted and or the question / wording is bad

Comment: Are you using "Run and Debug" rather than plain "Run" in VSCode here?

Comment: if by run and debug you mean ctrl shift d etc then yea I did do that it gives the same result

Comment: Please [edit] this question to include a [mre] of the code you're running

Comment: Do you have the "Raised Exceptions" option checked in "Breakpoints"? That would make VSCode behave like you're seeing. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52674581/why-is-try-except-block-not-working-in-visual-studio-code-for-python-3-7

Comment: oh my god slothrop thank you I had rasied exceptions checked under breakpoints It never crossed my mind to uncheck it after doing some error work with it earlier lol

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/6238) on github.

Uncheck **Raised Exceptions** in the **Breakpoints** panel can solve this problem.

[image]